# One more difference between width and max-width

Tags: html, css

Im styling card component. It contains img element and when I'm giving it(to the card component) a width of 100%, it of course it fills the parent containers width, but when I'm giving it max-width: 100%; the card grows only certain size (not the actual used picture width).

```css
/* 
=========
Fonts
=========
*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&family=Roboto&display=swap");
/* font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap");
/* font-family: 'Fraunces', serif;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; */

/* 
=========
Variables
=========
*/
:root {
  --clr-primary-cyan: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-cream: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
  --clr-dark-blue: hsl(212, 21%, 14%);
  --clr-dark-blue2: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  --clr-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --spacing: 0.25rem;
}

/* 
=========
Global Styles
=========
*/
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: var(--clr-dark-blue);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
p {
  color: var(--clr-dark-blue2);
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* page styles */
.main {
  background: var(--clr-primary-cream);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* card style */
.card {
  background: var(--clr-white);
  /* width: 23rem; */
  max-width:100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.card-picture {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.card-img-caption {
  letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
  color: var(--clr-dark-blue2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.card-info {
  padding: 1.25rem;
}
.card-header {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.card-text {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.prices {
  margin: 1rem 0 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.prices .price {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  color: var(--clr-primary-cyan);
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.prices .price-strike-through {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--clr-dark-blue2);
}
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background: var(--clr-primary-cyan);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Product preview card component</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <article class="card">
      <figure class="card-img">
        <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/50-x-50-icon/50-x-50-icon-28.jpg" alt="picture preview" class="card-picture">
      </figure>

      <div class="card-info">
        <div class="card-img-caption">
          perfume
        </div>
        <h1 class="card-header">Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge,
          Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
        </p>
        <div class="prices">
          <span class="price">$149.99</span>
          <span class="price-strike-through">$169.99</span>
        </div>
        <button class="add-to-cart-button btn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
          Add to Cart
        </button>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

I saw this behavior first time, nor can I find about it anywhere in internet.

Is this intended behavior with max-width or its side effect?

Answer (score 2):

`width: 100%;` will *force* the element to fill the parent's element's total width.
`max-width: 100%;` will *allow* the element to fill *up to* the parent's element's total width.

Meaning, if your picture is 250px:

- `width: 100%`: the picture will fill the container's width, no matter the original size of the image or the container's size (the image will be enlarged or shrunk to fit the container's width)
- `max-width: 100%`: the picture will only be 250px wide maximum; if your container is wider than 250px, the image  will not grow larger because although it is allowed to take all the container's width, it doesn't need to.

In your question: "not the actual used picture width", I disagree.
Right-click the following link (the picture in your example) and choose "Open in a new tab", you will see that the picture is 250x250 : https://icon-library.com/images/50-x-50-icon/50-x-50-icon-28.jpg

Comment: But if you open the code snippet, inspect the card element and instead of 'max-width:100%;' you give it 'width: 100%;' , you'll see that the card will occupy the whole page width. 

With 'max-width" 100% though, you'll see the card element with certain width, but what giving it that width? its not filling full page width and its not the picture (250x250) width either.

Comment: I must get different results than you...  
This is the result I get when I inspect the code snippet : https://imgur.com/a/ijM6nbm  
With `max-width: 100%`, I _do_ get 250x250.